# Using Branch.io link is not opened in Android

Tags: android, branch.io

I am new to branch.io but it's driving me crazy.

I just set up my link in branch.io dashboard like this:

```
Android URI scheme: http://www.foo.com/bar://
```

And also the fallback to google play store.

```
As well as the default URL http://www.foo.com
```

In my Android Manifest I entered this

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

And this under my main activity

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http://www.foo.com/bar" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

The link is still not opened in Android nor in Google Play.

The weird thing is that this link: https://foo.app.link/xxxxxx opens in Google play at the correct app page but has nothing in common with what I have in my branch.io setting.

Confused why there are two different logic behind the URI scheme.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch here: you're putting too much in the `scheme` field :). The Branch dashboard should have a URI scheme looking something like `foo://`, and the Android manifest should have `<data android:scheme="foo" android:host="open" />`

Comment: Thanks Alex for the tip. I reduced the scheme to only 'foo' in both ends and now the foo.app.link/xxxxxx works. Can you please specify why that opens in app but just www.foo.com doesn't? I could use the foo.app.link/xxxxxx but is the /xxxxxx part a secret I should not share?

Comment: I think you may be mixed up about the definition of a URI scheme. The scheme for `www.foo.com` is actually `http` or `https` and is just omitted by convention because http links are so common, so the two things aren't directly interchangeable. The `/xxxxxx` part of the URL is not secret at all — you are *supposed* to share that piece with Branch